# Javascript AST builder and code writer in Java

Tags: java, javascript, abstract-syntax-tree

Is there any Java library exists which allows me to create a Javascript AST in code then serialize the AST as a valid Javascript string?

The closest thing i have found is [escodegen](https://github.com/Constellation/escodegen) which is written in Javascript so i have to use Rhino or Node to execute it, but it accepts AST in [Mozilla Parser API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/SpiderMonkey/Parser_API) JSON definition. Java code only have to build a JSON then.

But i hope this is not the best possible thing, there should be something more Java native way of doing it.

Comment: There is an AST API in Rhino.

Comment: Nice, i will check that out. Does it allows writing the AST?

Comment: See _AstNode.toSource()_

Comment: Thanks, just checked it. Could you please answer it as a normal answer and i will accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried McDowell suggestion in the question's comments. Rhino's `AstNode.toSource()` is working as expected. I could build and serialize simple AST like this using Groovy:

```
    def astRoot = new AstRoot()
    astRoot.with {
        def expressionStatement = new ExpressionStatement()
        addChild(expressionStatement)
        expressionStatement.with {
            expression = new FunctionCall()
            expression.with {  
                target = new Name()
                target.identifier = "alert"

                def arg = new StringLiteral()
                arg.value = "Test"
                arg.quoteChar = '"'
                arguments = [ arg ]
            }
        }
    }

    println astRoot.toSource()
```

This prints: `alert("Test")`.